# Why clearInterval does not work in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    pulse = 0;
});

$('#food').bind('input', function() { 
    if ($(this).val() < 0.20) {
        start();
        pulse = 1;
    } else if (pulse == 1 && $(this).val() > 0.20) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
});

function start() {
    $('#food-circle').fadeIn(300).fadeOut(500);
    interval = setInterval(start, 800);
};
```

I don't know why, but I can't stop the interval "interval"...
I'm hoping someone can help me.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're attempting to do in this code.  But once you call `start()` then every 800ms you will overwrite the `interval` variable with a new additional interval.  Before long, *many* intervals will be running.

Comment: Try to store interval in a global variable so that it will be accessible anywhere.
Before document.ready create a variable interval and use the same.
Hope it will resolve the issue.

Comment: Also .bind is deprecated for .on and you should include the `$('#food').on('input', function() {  .. })`  inside the ready function

Comment: @deepak _"Try to store interval in a global variable..."_ - That's what OP does with `interval = setInterval(...)`

Comment: If you swap `interval = setInterval(start, 800);` to `interval = setTimeout(start, 800);` it would not have the issue, well it still could have the issue because it should probably check to see if a timeout is happening or you could be creating multiple

Comment: What ancient version of jQuery are you using bind() with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference to original `interval` is lost because it's being overwritten when `start` runs for the first time.

```js
$(function() {

  var pulse = false; // Use a boolean flag

  $('#food').on('input', function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    if (!pulse && value < 0.20) { // prevent starting again if there an internal alreay running
      start();
    } else if (pulse && value > 0.20) {
      stop();
    }
  });

  function start() {
    pulse = true;
    interval = setInterval(fadeAnimation, 800);
    // to run it without waiting 800ms (first time)
    fadeAnimation();
  };

  function fadeAnimation() {
    console.log('fadeAnimation');
  }

  function stop() {
    pulse = false;
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="food" />
```

You can improve the code by not polluting the global (window) scope. Try enclosing everything in an IIFE

Comment: No need for the pulse var

Comment: @mplungjan, I love how much you like to save bits :D. You're right!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .on and clear the interval whenever you call start

```js
$(function() {
  let interval;
  $('#food').on('input', function() {
    let val = $(this).val();
    if (val.trim() === "" || +val >= 0.20) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return
    }
    if (+val < 0.20) start();
  });

  function start() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(fadeAnimation, 800);
    // to run it without waiting 800ms (first time)
    fadeAnimation();
  };

  function fadeAnimation() {
    console.log('fadeAnimation');
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="food" />
```